# How dangerous is HTMLElement offsetTop property?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I'm only using webkit (Sencha Touch framework) and don't need to worry about older browsers, how likely am I to find that my code no longer works a little ways down the line?

Any better way to get this using Sencha framework code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `offsetTop` has existed in pretty much every browser since the dawn of time and is in the process of being [standardized](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop), I would say that it's not dangerous at all. Whatever framework you're using is much more likely to change its API than the browsers that have had this feature forever.

Naturally, `offsetTop` is [semi-broken](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t32) in older versions of IE, but if you don't need to worry about older browsers you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you -- I had seen that it was not yet standardized in the MDN docs and got a bit worried, but this confirms my hopes / suspeciion. thanks :)